# Separating custom type values using functors?

Tags: haskell, functor

I have the below type:

```
data Animals a = Cow a a | Dog a a deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
```

I've trying to apply different functions to each of the 'a' values associate with the animal instances.

E.g.

```
myCow = "Big" "White"

function1 :: Animals a -> Animals a
function1 cow = --do something with "Big", then something else with "White"
```

This won't work with my functor definition:

```
instance Functor Animals where
  fmap f (Cow a b) = Cow (f a) (f b) --I want to apply different functions to 'a' and 'b'!
```

How can I define my functor to enable this?

Comment: You can't. `fmap` only takes a single function as an argument, and there is no way for that function to make a distinction between the two values wrapped by `Cow` and `Dog`. If you redefine your type as a `Bifunctor`, you can apply separate functions via `bimap`.

Comment: @chepner Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `fmap` for your data type would be `(a -> b) -> Animals a -> Animals b`. This very tightly constrains the possible implementations of `fmap`, so much that there *is* only one possible implementation that obeys the functor laws (`fmap id == id`, `fmap (f . g) == fmap f . fmap g`).

```
instance Functor Animals where
  fmap f (Cow a b) = ???
  fmap f (Dog a b) = ???
```

First, you don't know anything about the function `f` other than it can be applied to each of the values wrapped by the data constructors, so that's all we can do with it.

Second, we know that the return value must be of type `Animals b`, and that we can't switch from `Cow` to `Dog` or vice versa (otherwise, `fmap id == id` would not hold). From this, we know the instance must look like

```
instance Functor Animals where
  fmap f (Cow a b) = Cow (f a) (f b)
  fmap f (Dog a b) = Dog (f a) (f b)
```

There is no room in the type signature to specify a second function `g`, and there is no way for `f` to know which "half" of the `Animals` value it is applied to for it to simulate two different functions.

---

If you instead redefine your type with

```
data Animals' a b = Cow a b | Dog a b
type Animal a = Animals' a a
```

you can define an instance of `Bifunctor` for `Animals'`, which defines a function `Bimap` that *can* apply a different function to each half.

```
instance Bifunctor Animals' where
  bimap f g (Cow a b) = Cow (f a) (g b)
  bimap f g (Dog a b) = Dog (f a) (g b)
```

You also get two additional functions `first` and `second` which apply a single function to only the first and second types wrapped by the type constructor. They have default implementations of `first f = bimap f id` and `second g = bimap id g`, so you don't need to define if you defined `bimap`. (Likewise, `bimap f g = first f . second g` by default, so it
would be sufficient to define the pair `first` and `second` instead of `bimap`.)

Make sure you never use `Animals'` directly to ensure that none of your functions will accept a chimaera like `Cow 3 "c"`.

Comment: "The only drawback to this approach is that your type no longer constrains the two values wrapped by the data constructors to have the same type" - just work with `type Animals' a = Animals a a`

Comment: You can even use `newtype Animals a = Animals (Animals' a a)`, which is itself a `Functor`.

Comment: @dfeuer You need the type alias so that you can still use `bimap`, no?

Comment: @chepner, well, only if you want to use it directly. You could always unwrap, bimap, rewrap. `bimapAnimals f g (Animals x) = Animals (bimap f g x)`

Comment: @chepner, maybe my prejudice is showing. I greatly dislike using type synonyms for almost any purpose. The one place I've seen them look really useful is for wrapping up higher-rank types, as in `lens`. I also don't mind the `Simple` type synonym in `lens`; I think that's probably because a simple lens tends to stay simple unless you do something a bit weird to it.

Comment: I try to avoid type synonyms, too (or at least to the extent that 90% of my Haskell programming, alas, is cherry-picking the easier questions posted here). I was thinking about a wrapper along the lines you posted, but didn't have a chance to actually think through what it would be.

Answer (score 1):

As chepner aptly demonstrated in their answer, you have a trilemma to deal with. There is no way of having `Animals` with fields of necessarily equal types while being able to map different functions over each field *and* enjoying the advantages of a well-known and widespread functor class -- you have to drop one of the three:

- You can keep the original type and write a `Functor` instance that does the same thing to fields homogeneously, which is what you are trying to avoid...
- ... or change `Animals a` to `Animals a b`, sacrificing one of your invariants in order to make a `Bifunctor` instance possible, which is chepner's solution...
- ... or content yourself with a mapping function specific to `Animals`, which has no generality but at least implements exactly what you want:

```
animalMap :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> Animals a -> Animals b
animalMap f g ani = case ani of
    Cow x y -> Cow (f x) (g y)
    Dog x y -> Dog (f x) (g y)
```

On the balance of things I have a slight preference for the third solution, however disappointing it may be.

---

The remainder of this answer is a long footnote in which I will show a way of making the third solution a little nicer. I am not suggesting that you actually use it -- it is almost certainly overkill for your use case -- but it is a nice possibility to be aware of.

As you know, one of the great things about functions in Haskell is that they can be composed:

```
GHCi> ((2+) . (3*) . (4+)) 1
17
```

Composition allows us to think about functions independently from the concrete data they affect. Being able to compose in a clean and easy way is beneficial in many ways, perhaps too many to list here.

Now, if you look again at `animalMap` and consider how similar it is to `fmap`, you would be justified in thinking that each *pair* of functions `a -> b` specifies a way to transform (via `animalMap`) an `Animals` just as much as any single function specifies a way to transform a list or any other `Functor` value (via `fmap`):

```
GHCi> let rex = Dog 2 5
GHCi> let ff = ((2*) . (1+), (3*) . (4+))
GHCi> (\(f, g) -> animalMap f g) ff rex
Dog 6 27
GHCi> -- Or, equivalently:
GHCi> uncurry animalMap ff rex
Dog 6 27
GHCi> -- A different pair:
GHCi> let gg = ((1+), subtract 3)
GHCi> uncurry animalMap gg rex
Dog 3 2
```

That being so, it would be reasonable to want to compose pairs of functions meant to be used with `animalMap`, just like regular functions are composed. Doing that in the immediately obvious way, however, is very messy:

```
GHCi> uncurry animalMap ((\(h, k) (f, g) -> (h . f, k . g)) gg ff) rex -- yuck
Dog 7 24
```

You can, of course, avoid writing that ugly lambda explicitly by using it to define a separate composition function, analogous to `(.)` but specific to your use case. That doesn't brighten things all that much, though.

The twist in this story is that there actually is a standard type class that generalises `(.)` beyond functions to other things that can be composed. That class is called [`Category`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html). If we define a new type for the paired functions, we can give it an instance of `Category` like this:

```
import Control.Category
import Prelude hiding (id, (.))

newtype Duof a b = Duof { runDuof :: (a -> b, a -> b) }

instance Category Duof where
    id = Duof (id, id)
    (Duof (h, k)) . (Duof (f, g)) = Duof (h . f, k . g)
```

Next, we might as well redefine `animalMap` in terms of `Duof`:

```
animalMap :: Duof a b -> Animals a -> Animals b
animalMap (Duof (f, g)) ani = case ani of
    Cow x y -> Cow (f x) (g y)
    Dog x y -> Dog (f x) (g y)
```

The net result is that composition is much neater:

```
GHCi> let ff = Duof ((2*) . (1+), (3*) . (4+))
GHCi> let gg = Duof ((1+), subtract 3)
GHCi> animalMap (gg . ff) rex
Dog 7 24
```

Do note that this new `animalMap` looks an awful lot like `fmap` for `Animals`, except that it takes a `Duof` instead of a function. In fact, there is nothing stopping us from defining a new type class called `DuofFunctor` with a method `duofmap :: Duof a b -> f a -> f b` and making `Animals` an instance of it -- nothing, that is, except that it is kind of pointless to define a new general-purpose class if you only need it for one instance. In any case, this `DuofFunctor` would correspond exactly to how you wanted to write the `Functor` instance before you realised it was impossible.

---

P.S.: A remark on naming conventions, unrelated to the question itself. Usually we would name your data type as `Animal`, rather than `Animals`. Even though your data type covers several species of animals, data types almost always have names in the singular, as these names are meant as a description of an individual value of that type (e.g. a cow is an `Animal`, and so is a dog).